# What is the web3 filter.watch() scope?

Tags: dapp-development, contract-debugging, web3js

If I create a nested filter.watch

```
filter_a.watch(
    filter_b.watch();
);
```

If I call

```
filter_a.stopWatching();
```

does filter_b.watch() go out of scope for web3.js?  Does geth keeps sending filter_b.watch() results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

filter b will still be polled and receive logs. And as you should provide a callback for filter b, this callback will still be called.

There is no "scope" here, as in JavaScript scopes for filters.

`filter_b.watch()` will simply take the callback given and call it as often as there are logs matching the callback come.